# ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES not working on PHP 5.2.9?

Tags: php, pdo

I have problem with this call:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(DB::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, 1);
```

On localhost I'm using `php 5.3` and everything works fine (columns in query result are prefixed with table name). Production server have `php 5.2.9`. The directive exists in that version, but is not working at all...

Is there any alternative to fetch prefixed column names (tablename.columnname) with `PDO` driver?

Answer (score 1):

A note from [PDO manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)

> Prepend the containing table name to each column name returned in the result set. The table name and column name are separated by a decimal (.) character. Support of this attribute is at the driver level; it may not be supported by your driver.

Does those versions use the same database driver? Run `phpinfo()` on your local and production servers and compare mysql/postgresql/mssql/whatever-database-you-use driver versions. `PDO` is just a wrapper for those drivers.

Comment: Thx fo reply. Production server has pdo_mysql api version 5.0, but on localhost is 5.1. Maybe is that problem?

Comment: I'm no expert at it. :) Consult to changelog of pdo_mysql, there might be some hints.